# batch copy loose files in their own folder to a new renamed folder

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, copy, rename

I am new here but I need help to copy a bunch of files that are all together in a folder into their own new separate folders.

So for example the file `ABCDE.EXT` needs to be copied into a folder that has to be created and renamed to the name `ABCDE`.

As this needs to be done a few hundred times, (on a Windows machine), it seems that a batch file, (or another program of some sorts), is the way to go.

Has anyone any thoughts on how I could accomplish this task?

Comment: Learned bash before Windows batch files and I can't say there is really a difference in search terms when trying to accomplish something programmatically. Pretty much the same for any language. Just use the language with your search term. I can guarantee  you that If you would have searched StaackOverFlow for this very question you would have found several answers. This question gets asked almost monthly.

Answer (score 0):

After formulating this question I understood the right search phrase and a web search found [this page](https://almost-a-technocrat.blogspot.com/2018/04/auto-create-folder-based-on-filename.html), answering my own question.

Auto create folder based on filename and move the file into it's folder:

Step 1 : Copy the Windows batch code below into your notepad and save it with filename "organize.bat".

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

Step 2 : Copy organize.bat file to the folder where there are files that you want to organize each file to be copy into a folder which has the same name as the filename.

Step 3 : Double click organize.bat file and watch the magic begins.